# How to pull data at index X from each row (aka columns) from array return by endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to grab each column's data that is returned from my endpoint. I can easily get the data row-wise and any specific [x][y] index. I've tried looking for existing methods but I haven't found one. I was then going to just loop through all the rows and grab the index I want on each iteration but the length method seems to be unavailable. Any suggestions? This is my current code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Query3 = () => {
    const [queryInfo, setQueryInfo] = useState([]);
    const queryId = 'query3';

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadQueryInfo = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/${queryId}`);
            const rows = response.data.rows;
            console.log(rows);
            setQueryInfo([response.data.rows.at(0).at(0)]);
        }
        loadQueryInfo();
    }, [queryId]);

    return (
        <>
        <p>This is the query result (Query 3): {queryInfo} </p>
        </>
    );
}

export default Query3;
```

And this is what is rendering

[image]

I'm trying to store all years in one array, countries in another array, etc.. I mean I know I could use a while loop but that just seems like a poor way to approach this. Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your expectation? We don't get it.

Comment: "store all years in one array, countries in another array" if you need to do this without duplicates use a Set by mapping the response

Comment: @cmgchess Thanks. How did I forget about mapping?